# WebStorm mark React render() function marked as unused field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm writing my React component in WebStorm\IntelliJ 2017.3 this way:

```
class Header extends React.Component {
   render = () => {
   }
}
```

The problem is that the IDE analysis mark the field `render()` as not used.

Is there something I can change in the project configuration to enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax for render is not arrow function, so you would be better to write it as bellow:

```js
class Header extends React.Component {
   render () {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try writing it the idiomatic way:

```
class Header extends React.Component {
   render() {
   }
}
```